# How to add validations for entities in silverlight project using silverlight-enabled wcf and entity framework

Tags: wcf, silverlight, entity-framework, validation, metadata

I'm using silverlight-enabled wcf service and entity framework for my silverlight business applicaiton. But there is no auto generated metadata class for the entities. So I can't easily add validations for the entities using DataAnnotations such as [Required], [ReadOnly(true)]...
I create a metadata class for the entities and here is the code on the server side:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(SAMPLE.SAMPLEMetadata))]
public partial class SAMPLE
{
    internal sealed class SAMPLEMetadata
    {
        private SAMPLEMetadata()
        {
        }

        [Required]
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public string SERIALNO { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is the code on the client side, which is in the service reference forlder and under the servicereference, the file name is Reference.cs:

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string SERIALNO {
        get {
            return this.SERIALNOField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.SERIALNOField, value) != true)) {
                this.SERIALNOField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("SERIALNO");
            }
        }
    }
```

So there is no DataAnnotaions generated like [Required]...
And the Validations of course never work.
I don't know how to add Validations using metadata class for silverlight-enabled wcf and entity framework.
Can some one help me about this?

Comment: You can add validation by using the view model class and by implementing the INotifyDataErrorInfo interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Can't be done easily in WCF, better use Ria Service